# Checking for Valid UK PostCode

Tags: firebird2.5

I have some code which is written in `mysql` (i think) to return valid postcodes, and I am trying to convert the code to `Firebird SQL` but I am getting errors. Stopping at the `CASE` part at the minute. What I want to happen eventually is for it to delete all non-valid postcodes. So if you know an another solution that would be of great help:

```sql
 SET TERM ^ ;

 CREATE PROCEDURE ValidatePostCode ( PostCode VARCHAR(8) ) 
 RETURNS ( ValidPC CHAR(1) )
 AS 

 BEGIN
 RETURN    CASE
        -- Special case GIR 0AA
        WHEN PostCode LIKE 'GIR 0AA' THEN i=1
        -- Current postcode prefixes
        WHEN    LEFT(Postcode, 2) NOT IN ('AB', 'AL', 'BA', 'BB', 'BD', 'BH', 'BL', 'BN', 'BR', 'BS', 'BT', 'CA', 'CB', 'CF', 'CH', 'CM', 'CO', 'CR', 'CT', 'CV', 'CW', 'DA', 'DD', 'DE', 'DG', 'DH', 'DL', 'DN', 'DT', 'DY', 'EC', 'EH', 'EN', 'EX', 'FK', 'FY', 'GL', 'GU', 'GY', 'HA', 'HD', 'HG', 'HP', 'HR', 'HS', 'HU', 'HX', 'IG', 'IM', 'IP', 'IV', 'JE', 'KA', 'KT', 'KW', 'KY', 'L', 'LA', 'LD', 'LE', 'LL', 'LN', 'LS', 'LU', 'ME', 'MK', 'ML', 'NE', 'NG', 'NN', 'NP', 'NR', 'NW', 'OL', 'OX', 'PA', 'PE', 'PH', 'PL', 'PO', 'PR', 'RG', 'RH', 'RM', 'SA', 'SE', 'SG', 'SK', 'SL', 'SM', 'SN', 'SO', 'SP', 'SR', 'SS', 'ST', 'SW', 'SY', 'TA', 'TD', 'TF', 'TN', 'TQ', 'TR', 'TS', 'TW', 'UB', 'WA', 'WC', 'WD', 'WF', 'WN', 'WR', 'WS', 'WV', 'YO', 'ZE')
            OR WHEN LEFT(Postcode, 1) NOT IN ('B', 'E', 'G', 'L', 'N', 'S', 'W') THEN 0
        -- AANN NAA
        WHEN PostCode LIKE '[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUWYZ][ABCDEFGHKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY][0123456789][0123456789] [0123456789][ABDEFGHJLNPQRSTUWXYZ][ABDEFGHJLNPQRSTUWXYZ]' THEN 1
        -- AANA NAA
        WHEN PostCode LIKE '[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUWYZ][ABCDEFGHKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY][0123456789][ABEHMNPRVWXY] [0123456789][ABDEFGHJLNPQRSTUWXYZ][ABDEFGHJLNPQRSTUWXYZ]' THEN 1
        -- ANN NAA
        WHEN PostCode LIKE '[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUWYZ][0123456789][0123456789] [0123456789][ABDEFGHJLNPQRSTUWXYZ][ABDEFGHJLNPQRSTUWXYZ]' THEN 1
        -- AAN NAA
        WHEN PostCode LIKE '[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUWYZ][ABCDEFGHKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY][0123456789] [0123456789][ABDEFGHJLNPQRSTUWXYZ][ABDEFGHJLNPQRSTUWXYZ]' THEN 1
        -- ANA NAA
        WHEN PostCode LIKE '[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUWYZ][0123456789][ABCDEFGHJKSTUW] [0123456789][ABDEFGHJLNPQRSTUWXYZ][ABDEFGHJLNPQRSTUWXYZ]' THEN 1
        -- AN NAA
        WHEN PostCode LIKE '[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUWYZ][0123456789] [0123456789][ABDEFGHJLNPQRSTUWXYZ][ABDEFGHJLNPQRSTUWXYZ]' THEN 1
        -- Not a valid postcode
        ELSE 0
    END

 END^

 SET TERM ; ^
```

Comment: Please specify the errors you get. The problem is most likely with your use of `LIKE`, you need to use `SIMILAR TO` for regular expressions: http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-similar-to.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing the following thanks to useful comment:

```sql
 select postcode from CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES
 where LEFT(postcode, 2) NOT IN ('AB', 'AL', 'BA', 'BB', 'BD', 'BH', 'BL', 'BN',        'BR',    'BS', 'BT', 'CA', 'CB', 'CF', 'CH', 'CM', 'CO', 'CR', 'CT', 'CV', 'CW', 'DA', 'DD', 'DE', 'DG', 'DH', 'DL', 'DN', 'DT', 'DY', 'EC', 'EH', 'EN', 'EX', 'FK', 'FY', 'GL', 'GU', 'GY', 'HA', 'HD', 'HG', 'HP', 'HR', 'HS', 'HU', 'HX', 'IG', 'IM', 'IP', 'IV', 'JE', 'KA', 'KT', 'KW', 'KY', 'L', 'LA', 'LD', 'LE', 'LL', 'LN', 'LS', 'LU', 'ME', 'MK', 'ML', 'NE', 'NG', 'NN', 'NP', 'NR', 'NW', 'OL', 'OX', 'PA', 'PE', 'PH', 'PL', 'PO', 'PR', 'RG', 'RH', 'RM', 'SA', 'SE', 'SG', 'SK', 'SL', 'SM', 'SN', 'SO', 'SP', 'SR', 'SS', 'ST', 'SW', 'SY', 'TA', 'TD', 'TF', 'TN', 'TQ', 'TR', 'TS', 'TW', 'UB', 'WA', 'WC', 'WD', 'WF', 'WN', 'WR', 'WS', 'WV', 'YO', 'ZE') OR LEFT(postcode, 1) NOT IN ('B', 'E', 'G', 'L', 'N', 'S', 'W')
 and postcode not SIMILAR TO '[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUWYZ][ABCDEFGHKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][ABDEFGHJLNPQRSTUWXYZ][ABDEFGHJLNPQRSTUWXYZ]'
 and postcode not SIMILAR TO '[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUWYZ][ABCDEFGHKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY][0123456789][ABEHMNPRVWXY][0123456789][ABDEFGHJLNPQRSTUWXYZ][ABDEFGHJLNPQRSTUWXYZ]'
 and postcode not SIMILAR TO '[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUWYZ][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][ABDEFGHJLNPQRSTUWXYZ][ABDEFGHJLNPQRSTUWXYZ]'
 and postcode not SIMILAR TO '[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUWYZ][ABCDEFGHKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY][0123456789][0123456789][ABDEFGHJLNPQRSTUWXYZ][ABDEFGHJLNPQRSTUWXYZ]'
 and postcode not SIMILAR TO '[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUWYZ][0123456789][ABCDEFGHJKSTUW][0123456789][ABDEFGHJLNPQRSTUWXYZ][ABDEFGHJLNPQRSTUWXYZ]'
 and postcode not SIMILAR TO '[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUWYZ][0123456789][0123456789][ABDEFGHJLNPQRSTUWXYZ][ABDEFGHJLNPQRSTUWXYZ]'
```

Before doing this however I removed all the spaces as they were not needed. If they were needed I would have put a space in the `similar to` string. Here is the code I used to remove the spaces:

```sql
 update CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES set POSTCODE = replace(POSTCODE, ' ', '');
```

Comment: Glad my comment helped!